# string replace method in pandas gives an unexpected result

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to change the values of 35 000 rows on a DataFrame using the string replace method. However, my solution does not return what I want and I can't figure out why it fails. Here is a simple example of the data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

liste = ['1_8','1_8','1_8','1_8','1_8','1_8','1_9', '1_9', '1_9','1_9','1_10','1_10','1_10','1_10','1_10','1_10','1_11','1_11']
mycooldataframe = pd.DataFrame(liste, columns =['bib'])
```

print(mycooldataframe)

```
    bib
0   1_8
1   1_8
2   1_8
3   1_8
4   1_8
5   1_8
6   1_9
7   1_9
8   1_9
9   1_9
10  1_10
11  1_10
12  1_10
13  1_10
14  1_10
15  1_10
16  1_11
17  1_11
```

I want to change 1_8 so that it becomes 108. Similarly, I want to replace 1_11 so that it becomes 110. I have tried to solve this using:

```
mycooldataframe['bib'] = mycooldataframe['bib'].str.replace('1_8', '108')
```

, which works fine. It gives me 108. But if I use:

```
mycooldataframe['bib'] = mycooldataframe['bib'].str.replace('1_10', '110')
```

that gives me 1010. Why doesn't it work? Is there a better way to solve this problem. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I used exactly your code and it seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: Your command works fine for me. What is it that you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: hmm.. it seems to work for my code example but not for dataset :/

Comment: I'm sorry. I find this so weird - any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your example works as expected.
If you're having issues with other cases, you can try using a dictionary:

```
value_map = {'1_8':'108', '1_10':'110'}
mycooldataframe= mycooldataframe.replace(value_map)
```

Comment: Your solution worked but I don't know why it solved the problem. Cheers